# Moved to acquire

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

The paragraph below is cited from Taipei Times

> After Japan withdraw its diplomatic recognition of the Republic of China(ROC) in 1972 in favor of Beijing, the People's Republic of China moved to acquire the ROC embassy in Japan as a "diplomatic asset."

How to explain "moved to acquire" in the paragraph above?

Does it mean:
the People's Republic of China put forward to    an requirement to acquire the ROC embassy in Japan and claim that the embassy is a diplomatic asset?

A little heads up:

ROC  refers to Taiwan

People's Republic of China refers to China

Two countries with a long unfathomable history

Comment: Shouldn't ROC refer to the Republic of China, and not Taiwan?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean.Did I misunderstand the meaning of "refer to"? I thought it means "equal" in a way?That is, Taiwan=ROC.

Comment: China (Beijing) can be referred to as PROC = People's Republic of China (the big one), Taiwan is ROC (Republic of China) aka Nationalist China aka Kwomingtang.

Comment: @Peter  I'm getting confused.

Comment: Did I use the term"refer to" wrong? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The word **move**, as StoneyB said, is intended to be generic. It is a term that is intended to include or "comprehend" any action necessary to achieve an end. We see the verb **move** often used in this manner in legal contexts, where it means "to take some (legal) action". http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/move    In other contexts, for example, a historical context describing the conquest of a kingdom, we might find "they moved to cut off all food supplies coming into the fortress".  They might have burned bridges, or stationed troops at crossroads, whatever might be necessary.

Comment: P.S. "put forward *to* a requirement" is not viable.  We could say "put forward a demand that..." (without "to") where "put forward" is roughly synonymous with "made" or "asserted".

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Didn't notice the "to".

Comment: Thank you @TRomano ! It's much more clearer now. Does it mean "by hook or by crook" but legally ?Or it doesn't have to be legal?

Comment: The phrase is not only generic but neutral. There is no implication one way or the other that the moves taken are nefarious or legitimate.  They "took action" or "acted" having an end in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Move* here has a very generic sense: "make an unspecified move" or "take unspecified steps".

In other words, the PROC did something unspecified to acquire the ROC's embassy—that is, to take the building out of Taiwan's possession and into its own. Apparently this had something to do with the legal status of a "diplomatic asset"; we may presume that China claimed that the building which houses an embassy belongs to whatever entity Japan recognizes as the "real" Republic of China.

Comment: Still don't understand the "move" here. The definition you gave is not listed  in my dictionary. Do you mean the "move" here means "to take action"?This is the closest meaning I can find.But none of them have a subtle meaning of "unspecified".

Comment: The "unspecified" here, do you mean the exact moves they took are just not mentioned on the newspaper or you mean the exact moves are unknown to the public?

Comment: "To make a move" = "to take action towards" some goal.  If you're standing in a bar and *someone* comes over and *makes a move* on you, it means they are trying to pick you up.  "Moved to acquire" = "sought ways to acquire" the embassy.  The exact steps to acquire the embassy may or may not be known to the public.

Comment: @JasmineKuo It's not "positively" unspecified, and there's no particular "subtlety" involved; it's merely that *move* itself does not specify any particular action, not even a literal physical "movement". By the same token, we don't know whether the nature of the action is unknown or merely unmentioned. Perhaps the article says more subsequently, but at this point all we know is that the PRC "did something".

Comment: @Stoney Thank you! Last question, do these steps have to be lawful?

Comment: @JasmineKuo It's not specified or implied.